# Why can't the child/dependent side be determined for this one-to-one relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, relationship

I am getting the usual error of:

> The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between 'Person.UserAccount' and 'UserAccount.Person'. To identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property. If these navigations should not be part of the same relationship configure them without specifying the inverse. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=724062 for more details.

In my case, UserAccount is a slave of Person, they have a relationship of one-to-zero/one and the foreign key is the field Id. I have set it up as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasOne(e => e.UserAccount)
            .WithOne(e => e.Person)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasForeignKey<UserAccount>(e => e.Id);
```

I have tried a whole other lot of combinations, read through the docs and other questions, but no matter what it's just not able to determine the child/dependent side.

UserAccount class:

```
[Table("UserAccount")]
public class UserAccount : EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }

}
```

Person class:

```
    [Table("PERSON")]
public partial class Person : EntityBase
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }

}
```

What is going on? what am I missing?

Comment: Can you show your classes (Person and UserAccount) code?

Comment: There you go @charbel, I have removed the data that doesn't concern the issue. let me know if there's anything missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `PERSON` table you have 2 properties that can possibly be a foreign key property which resulted in EF core being confused.
Can you try adding `[ForeignKey("PersonId")]` in `UserAccount` Class:

```
[Table("UserAccount")]
public class UserAccount : EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public Person Person { get; set; }

}
```

**EDIT:** 
Try also renaming your properties accordingly.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, however I am now realizing I am getting these errors in the output:----------------

> The foreign key properties haven't been configured by convention because the best match {'Id' : Guid} are incompatible with the current principal key {'Id' : int}. This message can be disregarded if explicit configuration has been specified.

Comment: Why do you need the `public Guid Id { get; set; }` ?

Comment: It's another field from the db. I have tried to rename the fields so that they match accordingly, and the error is gone, although now when it queries the database it hangs forever, but I guess it's a step forward, so I think if you reword your answer I can give it as valid.

Comment: This was a while ago and I guess you've fixed everything by now, but shouldn't the ForeignKey attribute above be "Person", not "PersonID"?